# How to identify elements in jquery to call a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a similar table like the one below. The table is filled dinamically so it could have many more rows. Each row has both select an input elements named with an id ending in "_" + number of row.

When an option is selected it should load the address for the person selected and place it next to the select that was clicked.

How could I use a single function in jquery to identify which select was used so I know in which row to include the result from the database.

For example: I choose Sam in the second row select. The function should detect in which row this happend, then I will call the database and place the returned data in the second row input.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<table id="tableAddess" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="name_1" id="name_1">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="1">John</option>
          <option value="1">Anna</option>
          <option value="1">Sam</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" disabled/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="name_2" id="name_2">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="1">John</option>
          <option value="1">Anna</option>
          <option value="1">Sam</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address_2" id="address_2" disabled/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="name_3" id="name_3">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option value="1">John</option>
          <option value="1">Anna</option>
          <option value="1">Sam</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address_3" id="address_3" disabled/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Look for ajax mysql query https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a class like `.select-name` to each select.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="select-name" name="name_1" id="name_1">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">John</option>
      <option value="1">Anna</option>
      <option value="1">Sam</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="address-field" type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" disabled/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And then use jQuery on change event.
I also added `.address-field` class to each input field, so i can find it easily by using: `$row.find('.address-field')` (see code below)

```
$('.select-name').on('change',function(){
   var $mySelect = $(this);
   var $row = $mySelect.closest('tr'); // the row where this select element is in.
   $.ajax({
       // blabla
   }).done(function(response){
     $row.find('.address-field').val(response)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `this` keyword wisely.

When javascript handles an event (like, select.change) you may use the `this` keyword to determine which select was changed.  From there you can use the relative position of html elements to locate, for example, the `<tr>` where that select is located.

Quick example (note that the TR IDs are only necessary because I'm displaying them in an alert):

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
  // two ways to do this

  //plain javascript - locate the tr relative to the select that was changed
  var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  //jquery has some nice features to do this more easily/robustly
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  alert(tr.id + " and jquery reports " + $tr.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id='this is TR1'><td><select><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></td></tr>
<tr id='this is TR2'><td><select><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></td></tr>
<tr id='this is TR3'><td><select><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select></td></tr>
</table>
```